# Unable to upload file to server using dropzone.js and PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am unable to upload images to my servers directory 'uploads'.

the user is supposed to be allowed to upload a photo listing to the server and then display it to other users to read.

I am using dropzone.js and PHP, the dropzone works just fine although when clicking upload nothing gets sent to the server or the folder! please help.

kindly note: this is a multipage form with a dropzone at the end. all fields are submitted in one table in one row. Also, I understand I am at risk of injections I'm just trying to get this stubborn functionality to work.

here is the HTML:

```
<head>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

    <div class="container" >
        <div class='content'>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="create.php" method="post" class="dropzone" id="dropzonewidget">
        
    </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-block flex-column flex-sm-row">
      <div class="col text-center text-sm-start"><a class="btn btn-link text-muted" href="user-add-2.php"> <i class="fa-chevron-left fa me-2"></i>Back</a>
      </div>
        <div class="col text-center text-sm-end"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">save</button><i class="fa-chevron-right fa ms-2"></i></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is create.php:

```
    <?php 

 session_start();
 include "db_conn.php";

if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && 
isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && 
isset($_POST['save']))
{

$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$user_name=$_SESSION['user_name'];
//form 1
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$type=$_SESSION['type'];

if(!empty($type) && $type != "option1" && $type != "option2" && $type != "option3"){
$ms[] = "Device not valid";
}
$country=$_SESSION['country'];
$city=$_SESSION['city'];
$state=$_SESSION['state'];
$zip=$_SESSION['zip'];
//form 2
$about=$_SESSION['about'];
$price=$_SESSION['price'];
//form 3

// PROCESS PHOTO IMAGE

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"] 
["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
$target_dir.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
$status = 1;}

{

//INSERT LISTING INTO HOST TABLE


$sql = "INSERT INTO hosts(id, user_name, name, type, 
country, city, state, zip, about, price, photo)
 VALUES('$id', '$user_name', '$name', 
'$type', '$country', '$city', '$state', '$zip', 
'$about', '$price', '$target_file')";
```

you may already see the problem as I am new to dropzone.js but if you could provide some insight/code as I have been researching for this past week and a half and I still cannot get a file uploaded.

after dropping a file and clicking save: all other inputs including $target_dir are uploaded but no file is found anywhere, please help!

Comment: Could you show how you create dropzone in javascript?

Comment: @Gandalf69 I'm using the provided "unpkg" script from the official dropzone.js site I can't access the javascript directly. (also it is very long)